# How do you use the class method for Data.Function.Memoize?

Tags: class, haskell, package, memoization

I am working on an NP search problem and was told I can speed up the search process by using [said](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.6/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html) package. Since memoisation is a new concept to me, I find it hard to wrap my head around anything other than the 'standard' memoised Fibonacci sequence.

In order to instantiate a data type 'a' as Memoizable I need to define a function memoize (:: (a-> v) -> a -> v) on it.

I have a Datatype data Formula which is in the classes (Eq, Ord, Show). I will have to define my own instance declaration, but don't know what function is expected.

What exactly is this function supposed to define for memoisation to work? The package description doesn't elaborate on this, and I doubt function application (which fits the type signature) will speed anything up.

Answer (score 5):

You should read about typeclasses. Here is how I understand the package.

The following definition is given:

```
class Memoizable a where
  memoize ∷ (a → v) → a → v
```

You should think of the memoize function as something like:

```
memoize :: (Memoize a) => (a → v) → a → v
```

Ie: you can apply it to a function from a to v iif an instance of `Memoize a` is declared. The package declare instances for some basic types like `Int`

So if you wish to memoize `compute :: Int -> WidgetData`, you shoud use `memoize compute` which has the same type without doing anything.

If you wish to memoize a function which takes as input a type without a Memoize instance, you will have to declare it yourself. More likely, you should rely on the template functions like `deriveMemoizable` to do that for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} -- put this at the top

deriveMemoizable ''T
```

> I doubt function application (which fits the type signature) will
>   speed anything up.

It depends of the problem at hands. If `compute` is expensive, and you call it twice with the same input, it will store the results and avoid computing them twice. If it is not the case, you will increase the memory usage of your program without any gain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

It is exactly this Instance declaration I am not sure about. I have a Datatype `data Formula` which is in the classes `(Eq, Ord, Show)`.

I will have to define my own instance declaration, but don't know what function is expected. I know sharing resources between recursive calls will be beneficial.

Comment: @Haxelaar see my edit. There are helpers for this at the end of the package documentation.

Comment: Had my first encounter with TemplateHaskell just now. Thanks for that. As of yet I cannot understand how the `Memoisable` instance-declaration translates to my datatype. To me it seems the type(?) variables `a` and `b` fall out of mid-air, I can't seem to shape that to my datatype

`data Formula = A | B | C | For O OT FormI FormI --Where FormI is a tupled (Formula, Int) and both O and OT don't have type parameters`

Will i need to read up on TemplateHaskell for this one, or could I resolve this without the extension?

Comment: @Haxelaar The `a` type variable does not `fall out of mid-air`. It is the parameter of the type class. It means that the instance knows what it is, and has access to an interface to implement the right behavior. `v` can be any type. It means that we can't assume anything about it. Think about `[a]`. You don't need to know anything about `a` to store it in a list. This is the same thing for `v` here.